# IOS/Swift: Parse JSON data and dictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to parse some nested JSON retrieved through an API but am having trouble isolating specific key-value pairs.  In fact, I have some confusion over the difference between the JSON data and the dictionary obtained through serialization.

To retrieve the data I am using:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 
                return
            }
```

To convert the data to a JSON dictionary, I am doing

```
do {
                let stringDic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
```

When printed, this produces nested output of the form:

```
Optional(["document_tone": {
    "tone_categories" =     (
                {
            "category_id" = "emotion_tone";
            "category_name" = "Emotion Tone";
  and so forth
```

My question is how can I get a unique value such as that for the key `category_name`?

If I try to use

```
let myCat = stringDic["category_name"]
```

Fix-it requires `let document_tone = stringDic?["document_tone"]` which if printed to console just prints whole dictionary over again.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: use json decoder with structs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty easy: `()` is array, `{}` is dictionary and the compiler must know the static types of all subscripted objects:

```
if let documentTone = stringDic?["document_tone"] as? [String:Any],
   let toneCategories = documentTone["tone_categories"] as? [[String:Any]] {
   for category in toneCategories {
       print(category["category_name"])
   }
}
```

Comment: What is difference between [String:Any] and [[String:Any]]

Comment: Dictionary (`[String:Any]`) vs. Array (`[[String:Any]]`)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to use `Decodable`

```
struct Root:Decodable {
     let documentTone : InnerItem 
} 
struct InnerItem:Decodable {
     let toneCategories: [BottomItem] 
}  
struct BottomItem:Decodable {
     let categoryId: String
     let categoryName: String 
}
```

---

```
do {
   let decoder = JSONDecoder()
   decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
   let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
   //print all names 
   result.documentTone.toneCategories.forEach {print($0.categoryName) }
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: You can omit all CodingKeys if you add the `keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase`

Comment: @vadian i think it's a good tip here , originally old parsed keys were not like that so i used to use codingKeys which let me drop that optimized way